# Find loop in a linked list containing millions of nodes

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

This was asked to me during an interview. I know several approaches to solve this question. But the emphasis was that it is containing **millions of nodes**.

I know we can solve this using two pointers approach. Also we can solve this using HashMap. He wanted to know the optimized solution as the list is having **millions** of nodes.

After that, I also suggested dividing the list into multiple chunks and then apply multithreading to fasten the process. But he was not full satisfied. Is there any other way which I am not focussing on. Using mulitthreading we also have to maintain a visited set of next nodes as when dividing the list into chunks, it is possible that the loop is divided into two parts.

I am not asking for any implementation. Just provide me with some direction so I can ponder more on it.

Comment: Why do you think HashMap approach isn't efficient?

Comment: HashMap approach is efficient. I told him about this. But he wanted more optimization. Using HashMap we have to traverse all the nodes and there are millions of nodes present.

Comment: How would you divide the list into chunks if you suspect the list to contain loops? And yes, of course, you must traverse all nodes. What if the last one looped on itself?

Comment: That is why he was not happy with the multithreading approach.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt - Agree, I started pondering over something elseunrelated to this question.

Comment: I gave lot of thoughts on this question. But didn't came up with any good solution. Kindly give some directional solution instead of downvoting.

Comment: Since you have to (potentially) visit every node at least once then you are not going to beat O(n), so it seems like a pointless question, unless they're just looking for micro-optimisations in the implementation rather than a better algorithm ?

Comment: @Paul you are correct. I was also thinking the same. Beating O(n) for finding any loop is very difficult. But the interviewer was not happy with the approach. Don't know why.

Comment: Maybe the distinction is between hash set and hash map? You could also number the list nodes ascendingly. Or you could refer to existing solutions for the task of cycle detection in a directed graph. In some cases, using a bitmap or a temporary map with backward pointers would also be interesting approaches.

Comment: It's not going to be possible to beat O(n) time but maybe he was after space optimisation. As an example of a trivial O(n) time O(1) space algorithm if you know the size of the list, count the nodes as you follow the list and if your count goes over the known size return true for cycles.

Comment: @All Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you started off with Floyd's algorithm (the two-pointer thing), and the interviewer then wanted you to suggest something faster, then you went in the wrong direction.  Maintenance of a HashMap would take *way* longer.  Multithreading is also not useful, because it's a linked list and you have to walk it to divide up the work.

I would have started with Brent's algorithm, which follows fewer pointers than Floyd's algorithm, and is often faster because it's cache-friendly.  Wikipedia has a good description of Brent's algorithm here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Brent.27s_algorithm

It's also possible to speed up Brent's algorithm in various ways.  Brent's algorithm ensures that you will visit no more than twice as many nodes as you really need to to find the cycle.  By storing more than 1 previous node in a *simple* 1-way associative hash (no collision avoidance), for example, you can reduce this factor until it's arbitrarily close to 1.